# Postfix datetime when backup the files in same folder

Tags: windows-10

When I backup a file or folder in a folder, I copy paste and rename it.

> D:/data.txt -> D:/data20200807.txt

Is there any software or system setting can do it so I won't have to press F2 and rename manually.
Just ctrl+c ctrl+v.

Comment: It sounds like you need a script that you can just drag and drop a file or folder into, and it will append the YYYYMMDD to the file before the .extension or in the case of folders appending the current dates YYYYMMDD to the end of the folder name. This sounds like the job for a script you can do this with. Probably a batch that calls PowerShell commands or scripts specifically (maybe even some AutoIT). If you clarify for Keith, he can likely get you all squared away with something or some variation, etc. Just be clear and specific what you need, but I think that's what it'll take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a context menu entry that renames the file by adding the current date string? If that's suitable, just copy the code below into a text editor, save as a `.reg` file, then right-click the new file & select `Merge`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Rename4Backup]
@="Rename (add date)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Rename4Backup\Command]
@="PowerShell -Command \"gi '%1' | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1:yyyyMMdd}{2}' -f $_.BaseName, ( Get-Date ), $_.Extension }\""
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about select-> ctrl+B-> copy-> rename

Comment: I don't understand your question. When I select an item in **Explorer**, `Ctrl+B` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. compile this autohotkey script and execute it
2. select the files and folders
3. press ctrl+b

`backup.ahk`

```
^b::

sel := Explorer_GetSelected()

yy := SubStr(A_Now, 3, 2)
today = %yy%%A_MM%%A_DD%
todaynow = %yy%%A_MM%%A_DD%%A_Hour%%A_Min%%A_Sec%

;; For each parameter (or file dropped onto a script):
Loop, Parse, sel, `n
{
  ;; Fetch the contents of the variable whose name is contained in A_Index.
  GivenPath := A_LoopField
  
  SplitPath, GivenPath, sfilename, dir, ext, name_no_ext, drive

  dot_ext = %ext%
  if (ext) {
    dot_ext = .%ext%
  }
  backup_fullpathname = %dir%\%name_no_ext%%today%%dot_ext%
  

  if FileExist(backup_fullpathname) {
    backup_fullpathname = %dir%\%name_no_ext%%todaynow%%dot_ext%
  }

  ;; file or folder
  if InStr(FileExist(GivenPath), "D") {
    FileCopyDir, %GivenPath%, %backup_fullpathname%
  } else {
    FileCopy, %GivenPath%, %backup_fullpathname%
  }

}
return

;; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60985-get-paths-of-selected-items-in-an-explorer-window/
Explorer_GetPath(hwnd="")
{
  if !(window := Explorer_GetWindow(hwnd))
    return ErrorLevel := "ERROR"
  if (window="desktop")
    return A_Desktop
  path := window.LocationURL
  path := RegExReplace(path, "ftp://.*@","ftp://")
  StringReplace, path, path, file:///
  StringReplace, path, path, /, \, All 
  
  ; thanks to polyethene
  Loop
    If RegExMatch(path, "i)(?<=%)[\da-f]{1,2}", hex)
      StringReplace, path, path, `%%hex%, % Chr("0x" . hex), All
    Else Break
  return path
}

Explorer_GetAll(hwnd="")
{
  return Explorer_Get(hwnd)
}

Explorer_GetSelected(hwnd="")
{
  return Explorer_Get(hwnd,true)
}

Explorer_GetWindow(hwnd="")
{
  ; thanks to jethrow for some pointers here
    WinGet, process, processName, % "ahk_id" hwnd := hwnd? hwnd:WinExist("A")
    WinGetClass class, ahk_id %hwnd%
  
  if (process!="explorer.exe")
    return
  if (class ~= "(Cabinet|Explore)WClass")
  {
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
      if (window.hwnd==hwnd)
        return window
  }
  else if (class ~= "Progman|WorkerW") 
    return "desktop" ; desktop found
}

Explorer_Get(hwnd="",selection=false)
{
  if !(window := Explorer_GetWindow(hwnd))
    return ErrorLevel := "ERROR"
  if (window="desktop")
  {
    ControlGet, hwWindow, HWND,, SysListView321, ahk_class Progman
    if !hwWindow ; #D mode
      ControlGet, hwWindow, HWND,, SysListView321, A
    ControlGet, files, List, % ( selection ? "Selected":"") "Col1",,ahk_id %hwWindow%
    base := SubStr(A_Desktop,0,1)=="\" ? SubStr(A_Desktop,1,-1) : A_Desktop
    Loop, Parse, files, `n, `r
    {
      path := base "\" A_LoopField
      IfExist %path% ; ignore special icons like Computer (at least for now)
        ret .= path "`n"
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if selection
      collection := window.document.SelectedItems
    else
      collection := window.document.Folder.Items
    for item in collection
      ret .= item.path "`n"
  }
  return Trim(ret,"`n")
}
```